# Organizing my reading list in Mendeley

Tags: reading, literature, reference-managers

I keep publications from the literature in Mendeley for later reading on my iPad. There are many publications, so I need some sort of way of prioritizing the ones I need to read first versus the ones I might read someday. Right now, I use folders with varying priority levels. The biggest problem is that I cannot move articles to different folders on the iPad, so I have to do this prioritization while I'm at my computer (where I usually have more important things to do). Also, I feel like I spend most of my time assigning priorities to articles rather than reading them, which is not ideal.

Do you have better suggestions on how to prioritize and organize the publications I want to read using Mendeley?

Comment: Can you use tags instead of folders? I think you and add and remove tags using the iOS client, but don't have one handy to check.

Comment: My other question would be what you're trying to accomplish with prioritization. Maybe instead of pre-sorting them you could just search for a keyword or author or tag to pull up the ones you want on-demand?

Comment: You can add and remove tags but I don't think you can search by tag. I'm not looking for specific papers, I need a list of papers I should read now, soon, or someday.

Comment: Yes, you can search by tag (in the desktop version only, though. Not online, afaik). If, for example, you want to find the papers tagged with the word `andrea`, you just type `tag:andrea` in the search box.

Answer (score 8):

One option would be to create a tags P1, P2, P3, P4 ... and assign "rating" to articles how much priority they have. Tags could be updated as priority changes.

(similar system could be used with Delicious.com tags to websites)

Tags are more flexible then folders. Mainly - Multiple membership in more than one tags